# Error after installing Ubuntu Elastic Search

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed java SDK 8 and elastic search 6.8. When I restarted elastic search, I got this error:

> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.

and when I run `journalctl -xe`, i get this error:

> bitmask-vpn[21283]: Using '/tmp' paths in SNAP environment will lead
>   to unreadable resources

What I have done to solve this issue:

a. I made sure that I have Java SDK 8. When I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it returns

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

b. Then I went to

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

and commented out `httpport`

c. I have also run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

The issue still persists.

Comment: r u using tar based installation ?

Comment: also is it a fresh installation or you are migrating from older to newer version ?

Comment: can you share the procedure you used for the installation?

Comment: I removed excess text to make the problem read more fluently. Errors were formatted to make them more immediately recognizable. The title was modified to more clearly reflect the problem to be solved.